# Scanning Assets folder

Tags: android, assets

Is there a way to scan assets folder on launching app every time?Because i stored  images in assets folder and have saved state of app using preference.When i load new images to assets folder i found it doesn't scan for new files and returns old app state.It works only if i delete previous app.So i would like to know if there is a way to scan assets folder or how to change preference state of app?
i use this to read assets folder

```
  String[] getImagesFromAssets() {
AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
String[] img_files = null;
try {
   // img_files = getAssets().list("pictures");
    img_files = assetManager.list("pictures");

} catch (IOException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(GameActivity.class
            .getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
return img_files;


   }

      void loadImage(String name) {
    AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();

    try {

      InputStream ims = assetManager.open("pictures/" + name);


        Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(ims, null);
        image.setImageDrawable(d);


    } catch (IOException ex) {
        return;
    }
```

Comment: How to added new images into Assets?

Comment: @MD i copy-paste few images and added to existing folder in assets

Comment: can you added this images at Run time?

Comment: @MD I added new image files to existing app version and overwrite previous installed app.when i clear preference i found all new files along with old one.But you could see only if preference gets cleard

Comment: You cannot update the assets folder after the application has been installed. After installation if you do any changes in the resources it will not reflect to your older installed version.As Asset folder is read only , you cannot write or update any file present there.

If you want to update it then you need to uninstall the older version and install new version. and you will need to use local storage to work with new files that your application creates.

Comment: @MD i understand and i tried to export my files stored on assets folder to sd card location.But what i see is the image file copies on folder only when images from assets folder loads to app.i couldn't copy entire files say 50 image as a whole to folder.How to achieve this?

Comment: @MD any alternate solution ?......

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46485/discussion-between-m-d-and-govind-narayan)